# MongoDB replicates data to all shards

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicate

I have 4 servers in a test environment which I use to test MongoDB replica and distribution:
RepSetA holds RepSetA1 and RepSetA2.
RepSetB holds RepSetB1 and RepSetB2.
All servers act as routers, RepSetA1 acts as a single config server.

I have a "Player" data (10,000 records, the object consists an "Id" and a "Name" fields), and I want it to be sharded (or distributed) between the replica sets, and cloned among the servers in the same replica set. So, just for a plain example:
Player1-5000: Exists in both RepSetA1 and RepSetA2, but not in RepSetB1 and RepSetB2.
Player5000-10000: Exists in both RepSetB1 and RepSetB2, but not in RepSetA1 and RepSetA2.

**What I get instead is having all players in all 4 servers.**

If I print the sharding status, I get the following:

```
mongos> db.printShardingStatus();

--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 3 }
  shards:

        {  "_id" : "RepSetA",  "host" : "RepSetA/MongoRepSetA1:27018,MongoRepSetA2:27018" }
        {  "_id" : "RepSetB",  "host" : "RepSetB/MongoRepSetB1:27018,MongoRepSetB2:27018" }
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
        {  "_id" : "GamesDB",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "RepSetA" }
                GamesDB.Player chunks:
                                RepSetA 2
                        { "_id" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : 0 } on : RepSetA { "t" : 1000, "i" : 1 }
                        { "_id" : 0 } -->> { "_id" : { $maxKey : 1 } } on : RepSetA { "t" : 1000, "i" : 2 }
        {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "RepSetB" }
        {  "_id" : "EOO",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "RepSetB" }
```

I used the following commands to build the shards:

```
db.adminCommand( { addShard : "RepSetA/MongoRepSetA1:27018,MongoRepSetA2:27018" } )
db.adminCommand( { addShard : "RepSetB/MongoRepSetB1:27018,MongoRepSetB2:27018" } )
db.runCommand( { enablesharding : "GamesDB" } );
db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "GamesDB.Player", key : { _id :1 } , unique : true} );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you query to see which players exist on which shard?

Comment: using MongoVue GUI, and even tried connecting to the specific server and perform a "db.Player.find().limit(100);"

Answer (score 0):

If you connect through a mongos process to your nodes, it will look like all contain the data. From your output, It doesn't look like all data is available on all nodes. RepSetA holds 2 chunks and RepSetB should contain none. You can verify this by connecting directly with your nodes rather than through mongos.
By the way, if you're using MongoDBs ObjectId as your _id(shard key), consider to shard on another key as this will cause all inserts be made into one node as the key changes monoton.

Comment: I still see the same records in both RepSetA1 and RepSetB1 (which sit on different replica sets), if I connect them directly using MongoVue or Mongo.exe shell.

Comment: As gregor and me pointed out, the data is correctly sharded and not copied to all nodes. Did you very that you connected to RepSetB and not accidently to RepSetA? What version are you using? The only thing I can imagine, what may cause this phenomenom is that mongo.exe and MongoGUI are automatically connect to a mongos rather than mongod. Anyway I highly doubt, that this is the case. RepSetA and RepSetB actually point to different IPs/Servers? Maybe those are pointing to the same so it looks like you have RepSetA and RepSetB while only having RepSetA.

Comment: I tried querying the servers of RepSetA (MongoRepSetA1 & MongoRepSetA2) - which holds 10,000 inserted records, and the same 10,000 records also appear in the servers of RepSetB (MongoRepSetB1 & MongoRepSetB2). I double-checked everything. I'm using the latest Mongo release (mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.0.5). BTW, I just tried deleting one of the records from MongoRepSetA1 using the MongoVue, and it deleted it from all other nodes as well.

Comment: Hmm, I really only can imagine that your DNS settings are not properly done so that you connect to the same system always. Can you paste some output you get when you connected to your given nodes, so we can verify thats the one you expect to be on)? Please test through [isMaster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#isMaster) that you're really on SetA or SetB.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. It does not show that all data is on all servers. The output shows that all chunks (data) of GamesDB.Player are on shard RepSetA

```
 GamesDB.Player chunks:
                            RepSetA 2
                    { "_id" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : 0 } on : RepSetA { "t" : 1000, "i" : 1 }
                    { "_id" : 0 } -->> { "_id" : { $maxKey : 1 } } on : RepSetA { "t" : 1000, "i" : 2 }
```

This means that the balancer has not started to balance your chunks. The balancer only kicks in when there is an 8 chunk difference. 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration#ShardingAdministration-Balancing

You can force balancing by manually splitting chunks (if you want to) 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Splitting+Shard+Chunks

Or you can reduce the chunk size if you want to see balancing sooner. 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration#ShardingAdministration-ChunkSizeConsiderations

Comment: It looks fine, but I see the same records in both RepSetA1 and RepSetB1 (which sit on different replica sets), if I connect them directly using MongoVue or Mongo.exe shell.